# How can I change errorElem?

Tags: parsley.js

I am trying to change how the error element is displayed. I am using the Bulma UI framework, and want the error message to be displayed in the following. The structure should look like the following. It should also remove the "li" tags around the error message:

```
<article class='message'>
    <div class="message-body content">
         <p> ERROR DISPLAYS HERE </p>
    </div>
</article>
```

My attempt to fix it was as follows:

```
const parsleyConfig = {
    errorElem: '<div class="message-body"></div>',
    errorsWrapper: '<article class="message"></article>'
};

$('#myForm').parsley(parsleyConfig);
```

However, only the errorsWrapper seems to be working, the errorElem does not apply to the error message at all.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Parsley are you using? `errorElem` is Parsley 1.x...

Use `errorsContainer`, `errorsWrapper`, and `errorTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

As Marc-André Lafortune stated, you're using Parsley.js v1.x.x, so `errorsWrapper` and `errorElem` should be defined in `errors` configuration. Here is a simple implementation of [Parsley.js v1](http://parsleyjs.github.io/Parsley-1.x/documentation.html) based on your code:

```js
$(function() {

    const parsleyConfig = {
        errors: {
            container: function (elem) {
                return elem.next('article.message');
            },
            errorsWrapper: '<div class="message-body content"></div>',
            errorElem: '<p></p>'
        }
    };

    $('#myForm').parsley(parsleyConfig);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/1.2.3/parsley.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="field" parsley-required="true">
    <article class="message"></article>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>
```

And here is a [Parsley.js v2](https://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html) implementation:

```js
$(function() {

    const parsleyConfig = {
        errorsContainer: function (elem) {
            return elem.$element.next('article.message');
        },
        errorsWrapper: '<div class="message-body content"></div>',
        errorTemplate: '<p></p>'
    };

    $('#myForm').parsley(parsleyConfig);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.9.1/parsley.js"></script>

<form action="" method="" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="field" required>
    <article class="message"></article>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>
```